# Can not found jar file in persistence.xml

Tags: jpa

I'm trying to use the jar-file tag in persistence.xml to found a jar file that contains some managed classes with annotations (@Entity, @Table ...).

So i tried it:

```
<jar-file>lib/myjar-2.0.jar</jar-file>
```

My jar is deployed in WEB-INF/lib folder but the eclipse shows error:

```
JAR file "lib/myjar-2.0.jar" cannot be resolved
```

My jar file don't have any persistence.xml just managed classes.

When i try to start my application in tomcat i got the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on br.com.projecta.bean.Acervo.usuario references an unknown entity: br.com.myjar.security.bean.User
```

Comment: Eclipse shows an error. But What happens when you actually deploy the application?

Comment: I edited my post with error.

Comment: Where is the persistence.xml file located in the deployed application? Is it in a jar under WEB-INF/lib, or in WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: it is in a META-INF folder

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Is it under WEB-INF/classes, or inside a jar file of WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: it is under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF to be more specific.

Comment: Then according to the spec, it should work correctly. Try with just myjar-2.0.jar.

Comment: I already tried it and didnt work.

Comment: did you get any further with this? Which Eclipse version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but I had a similar problem.

In my case, the problem was that Eclipse did not have myjar-2.0.jar on the build path...

The solution for me was to go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path-> Libraries and add myjar-2.0.jar there...

Hope it helps somebody.